# When objects in Java are partially initialized ( an exception occurs in the constructor )

Tags: java

I've heard that it is possible to write some code like this

```
SomeClass obj = null;

try {
    obj = new SomeClass();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
...
}
...
if ( obj != null ) { // here it holds true
...
}
```

Can somebody please explain, is that possible at all and under what conditions if we assume that constructor SomeClass *may* throw an Exception?

Another example:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Sample{

    static class A {

        public static A s;

        public A(Collection c) {
            c.add(this);
            s = this;
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testResource() throws Exception {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        A a = null;
        try {
            a = new A(l);
            fail("Oops");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
        }
        assertTrue(l.size() == 1);
        assertNull(a);
        assertNotNull(A.s);
        assertNotNull(l.get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the source of that suspicious info?

Comment: @Laurent: mat be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909818/java-exception-thrown-in-constructor-can-my-object-still-be-created

Comment: @HarryJoy See Hazok's ansewr to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086334/is-it-good-practice-to-make-the-constructor-throw-an-exception It's apparently a security vulnerability for a non-final class to throw an exception. I haven't yet formulated how to confirm or disprove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you declare and initialize a variable.

```
SomeClass obj = null;
```

In the following lines you (1) create a new instance and (2) store the reference.

```
try {
   obj = new SomeClass();
} catch ( Exception e ) {
   ...
}
```

Now we assume, the instantiation (Step 1) fails and throws an exception: the JVM will continue in the next catch block that handles that exception. So step 2 will not be executed and the variable will keep its actual state.

Now is is *possible* that an instance has been initialized partially. Honestly, I don't know, that's JVM internal. But as nothing holds a reference to this partially initialized instance, it will be gc'd on the next occasion.

Comment: +1 One would think the partially initialized instance does exist in memory until it gets GC'd, since constructors are just special methods that initialize an object after its instantiation. Seems like it would take extra work for the JVM to cancel this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible.

I'm not sure I understand your question though, you've answered it yourself:  *if* the constructor throws an exception, obj could be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write code like that, and it will compile and run just fine.  But there will never be a case where `obj` is "partially initialized".  Either it will be, or it won't be.  Specifically, if this line throws an `Exception`:

```
obj = new SomeClass();
```

Then it is as if that line was never executed, as far as the value of `obj` is concerned.  You initialize `obj` to `null` prior to that line, so if an exception is thrown then `obj` will still be `null`.  In that case the program will not go into the `if` block at the end.

Or, if an exception is not thrown, then `obj` will no longer be `null`, and the code inside of the final `if` block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible; look closer: if the constructor throws an exception, `obj` will still be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `SomeClass` constructor throws an Exception `obj` will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

For me the object is null even after calling constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestCls cls = null;
    try {
        cls = new TestCls("");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(cls == null)
        System.out.println("hi");
}

public TestCls(String str) throws Exception{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Output:-

```
java.lang.Exception
hi
    at TestCls.<init>(TestCls.java:57)
    at TestCls.main(TestCls.java:48)
```

---

**Conclusion**: If the `class constructor` throws an `Exception` then the `obj` will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor could throw an Exception, just like any other call in Java could.  For instance it may throw a NullPointerException if trying to call a method on a null reference.  Consider the following example:

```
public class ConstructionTest {

    static ConstructionTest obj;


    public ConstructionTest() {
        String s = null;
        s.hashCode();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            obj = new ConstructionTest();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        if ( obj != null ) { 
            System.err.println("Not Null");

        } else {
            System.err.println("Is Null");
        }

    }

}
```

As s is null in the Constructor a NullPointerException is thrown, so "Is Null" gets printed.  There is no concept of a "partially constructed Object" - when you use new in Java it either works and you get the newly instantiated Object back or it doesn't work and you get the Exception.