# The value is displayed incorrectly when multiplying

Tags: javascript, math

I have obscurity. Why if I multiply

```
8.2 * 1000000 = 8199999.999999999
```

But if i mul to

```
8.2 * 1000 = 8200
```

Maybe advice me topic about this issue.

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point representation of JavaScript has a limited accuracy; its resolution decreases as the absolute value of the data grows (which is the case for all implementations of floating point data types). This is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440375/invoking-virtual-method-in-constructor-difference-between-java-and-c).