# Invoke method that throws an exception in a different class

Tags: java, exception, constructor, singleton, private

I have the below code where I am lazy loading the instance creation of my class.

```
public class MyTest {
private static MyTest test = null;
private UniApp uniApp;  

private MyTest(){
    try{                        
        uniApp = new UniApp("test","test123");          
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception " +e+ "occured while creating instance of uniApp");
    }   
}

public static MyTest getInstance(){
    if (test == null){
        synchronized(MyTest.class){
            if (test == null){
                test = new MyTest();
            }
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

In the constructor, I am creating an instance of UniApp that requires passing userid, password in its own constructor. If lets say I pass a wrong userid, password of the uniApp object, uniApp doesn't get created. Here is what I need -

I am invoking the getInstance method in a different class -

```
    MyTest test=MyTest.getInstance();
```

And here, I want to add condition if failure of creation of uniApp happens, do blah. How do I do that?
In general, if I am trying to invoke a method that throws an exception in class A in class B, and put a condition in B - if the method in class A throws exception, do this.

How can I achieve this? Let me know if my question is confusing. I can edit it :)

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing an exception from your private constructor would be ok (reference [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086334/is-it-good-practice-to-make-the-constructor-throw-an-exception), or do some quick Googling).  In your case, you are catching the exception thrown from `new UniApp()` and not passing it along - you can very easily pass that exception up the foodchain into your `getInstance()` method and then to whomever calls that singleton.

For instance, using your code:

```
private MyTest() throws UniAppException { // Better if you declare _which_ exception UniApp throws!
    // If you want your own code to log what happens, keep the try/catch but rethrow it
    try{                        
        uniApp = new UniApp("test","test123");          
    }
    catch(UniAppException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception " +e+ "occured while creating instance of uniApp");
        throw e;
    }   
}

public static MyTest getInstance() throws UniAppException {
    if (test == null) {
        synchronized(MyTest.class) {
            if (test == null) {
                test = new MyTest();
            }
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

To create your "if" condition to test whether the `getInstance()` method works or not, surround your call to `getInstance()` with a try/catch block:

```
...
MyTest myTest;
try {
    myTest = MyTest.getInstance();
    // do stuff with an instantiated myTest
catch (UniAppException e) {
    // do stuff to handle e when myTest will be null
}
...
```

Since you haven't shown what *actually* calls `MyTest.getInstance()` I can't tell you what else to do besides that.

Comment: Sorry don't think you've answered my question here. Throwing the exception is OK, but how do I write a if condition - if getInstance throws exception, do this?

Comment: Edited to show how to catch the exception in code which was not provided.