# Should I throw an Exception in my API if I have bad object creation request?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to APIs and don't know if I should do it, for example, if one of the fields during creation was not validated I throw InvalidRequestException with message ('field' has 'problem description' ).

Comment: If you are asking for "permission" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086334.  If you are asking for advice as to when you should do it ... well the answer is (IMO) pretty much the same as whether / when a method should throw and exception (and what kind of exception is appropriate).

Comment: You mean your Web API? Or some Java Service API?

Comment: @BenjaminM - Well Web APIs don't throw exceptions ....

Comment: @StephenC Sure it does, but get catched by Spring's Exception Handler and then is getting transformed to some desired HTTP output (for example JSON). See: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc or https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: But that isn't the Web API.  That's the Java API.  The Web API is the HTTP request / responses.  Or at least, that is how that term is *normally* used; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API

Comment: you can probably return 400 Bad request instead of an exception